# Where to add i18n files in a project (for my case GWT)?

Tags: gwt, internationalization

I can't find a good answer to this simple question:
Where can I add my i18n files in a GWT project ?

I see two solutions:
- create a module and add all i18n files for this module in this module
- create a complete different structure to put all i18n files (no matter what module) in the same directory (and so, easy to create a new language)

My feeling is that the second approach is better but in gwt samples, it's the first approach which is generally used.

And you, what do you do with yours i18n files ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Create a separate package in your module. Dump all message files there along with the property files.
2) As a best practice create a base message class and EXTEND other message interfaces from the base one. You can reference base message class in code and depending on which instance of message class you point too, your actual value will change.

Another approach, create a new i18n module and inherit that in your actual model.

1) Allows all messages to be in one place.
2) Easy to hand over to localization people for translation.

Answer (score 1):

I usually put the i18n files (*.properties) in the same package as the `Constants` (or any other i18n related class) derived interface that's using them (less hassle with setup) - usually the package is named `i18n`.